Flutter app freezes when retrieving data from database
I'm creating a flutter app that graphs temperature and heart rate values stored in a database, but upon navigating to the page that shows the graphs the app freezes with a circular loading bar. I had previously gotten it to show the graph before but the x-axis values shown are not timestamps. I used the getHourLabel method to convert them into hour:minute values, but when the code is run using AxisTitles bottomTitles(), the graph does not load and the app freezes.
Graph Page:
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:fl_chart/fl_chart.dart';
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';
import 'package:supabase_flutter/supabase_flutter.dart';
import 'dart:math';

class Temperature extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _TemperatureState createState() => _TemperatureState();
}

class _TemperatureState extends State<Temperature> {
  String? _deviceID;
  final String graphTitle = 'Skin Temperature';

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _fetchDeviceID();
  }

  void _fetchDeviceID() async {
    final user = Supabase.instance.client.auth.currentUser;
    if (user != null) {
      final String? userEmail = user.email;
      if (userEmail != null) {
        final response = await Supabase.instance.client
            .from('user_profile')
            .select('device_id')
            .eq('email_address', userEmail)
            .single();

        setState(() {
          _deviceID = response['device_id'] ?? '';
        });
      }
    }
  }

  Future<List<FlSpot>> fetchTemperatureData(String deviceId) async {
    final response = await Supabase.instance.client
        .from('temp_test')
        .select('created_at, value')
        .eq('device_id', deviceId)
        .order('created_at', ascending: true);

    List<FlSpot> spots = [];
    if (response.isNotEmpty) {
      final List<dynamic> data = response;
      spots = data.map((record) {
        final DateTime timestamp = DateTime.parse(record['created_at']);
        final double temperature = record['value'].toDouble();
        final double xValue = timestamp.millisecondsSinceEpoch.toDouble();
        return FlSpot(xValue, temperature);
      }).toList();
    }
    return spots;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Temperature History'),
        backgroundColor: const Color.fromARGB(255, 245, 110, 110),
      ),
      backgroundColor: Colors.black,
      body: _deviceID != null
          ? FutureBuilder<List<FlSpot>>(
              future: fetchTemperatureData(_deviceID!),
              builder: (context, snapshot) {
                if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
                  return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
                } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
                  return Center(child: Text("Error: ${snapshot.error}"));
                } else if (snapshot.hasData) {
                  final minY = snapshot.data!.map((e) => e.y).reduce(min);
                  final maxY = snapshot.data!.map((e) => e.y).reduce(max);
                  return LineChartWidget(
                    spots: snapshot.data!,
                    minY: minY,
                    maxY: maxY,
                  );
                } else {
                  return Text('No temperature data available');
                }
              },
            )
          : Center(child: Text("Device ID not found")),
    );
  }
}

class LineChartWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final List<FlSpot> spots;
  final double minY;
  final double maxY;

  LineChartWidget({
    required this.spots,
    required this.minY,
    required this.maxY,
  });

  // Helper method to format date from milliseconds since epoch to hour.
  String getHourLabel(double millisecondsSinceEpoch) {
    var date =
        DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(millisecondsSinceEpoch.toInt());
    return DateFormat('HH:mm').format(date);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    double chartWidth = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;

    AxisTitles bottomTitles() {
      return AxisTitles(
        sideTitles: SideTitles(
          showTitles: true,
          reservedSize: 22,
          getTitlesWidget: (value, meta) {
            return Text(getHourLabel(value),
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 10));
          },
          interval: 1, // Adjust the interval as needed
        ),
      );
    }

    return SingleChildScrollView(
      scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
      child: Container(
        width: chartWidth * (spots.length / 10), // Adjusted for scrolling
        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 2,
        child: LineChart(
          LineChartData(
            minX: spots.first.x,
            maxX: spots.last.x,
            minY: minY,
            maxY: maxY,
            lineBarsData: [
              LineChartBarData(
                spots: spots,
                isCurved: false,
                color: Colors.green,
                barWidth: 2,
                isStrokeCapRound: true,
                dotData: FlDotData(show: false),
                belowBarData: BarAreaData(show: false),
              ),
            ],
            titlesData: FlTitlesData(
              bottomTitles: bottomTitles(),
              leftTitles: AxisTitles(
                sideTitles: SideTitles(
                  showTitles: true,
                  getTitlesWidget: (value, meta) {
                    return Text('${value.toInt()}°C',
                        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 10));
                  },
                  interval: 1,
                ),
              ),
            ),
            gridData: FlGridData(show: false),
            borderData: FlBorderData(
                show: true, border: Border.all(color: Colors.white)),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

How do I makes changes so that the x-axis values are hour:minute values and the graph loads without freezing the app.
